# Issue created a button in layout (Android)?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use two buttons in one layout:

- a button to notes, which is working below
- a button to calculator (button10)

I get this error on super.oncreate:

```
"The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object"
```

**main.java:**

```
public class IzzynActivity extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, notes.class);
                IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
                wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, calculator.class);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
        });

            }


}
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one onCreate method per Activity is permitted. The two answers bellow have your problem all sorted out. Perhaps you should read a couple HelloAndroid tutorial in order to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you did in that class but if you want two buttons in your layout then put them in your layout and search for them in the activity's `onCreate` method:

*R.layout.main*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button10" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button wg1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, notes.class);
                IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        Button wg10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
                wg10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, calculator.class);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
        });
```

Comment: The button works. But instead of taking me to calculator.class it takes me to the home screen...

Comment: @user1248404  `setResult` is used when you start this activity from another activity with `startActivityForResult()` and expect a result when the activity finishes. If all you want is to start the `calculator` class on button click then simple use what you used in the first click listener: `Intent myIntent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, calculator.class);
                IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);` . the method `finish()` is used when you are closing the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you've done but you've messed up your code big time. My assumption is that you've been copying a tutorial without reading what's actually going on and therefore not really understanding what you're doing.

Here is what your code should look like (untested, I've just typed this up now, but this is the jist).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find the first button and set an on click listener
        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, notes.class);
                IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        // find the next button and set an on click listener
        Button otherButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
        otherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(IzzynActivity.this, calculator.class);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Read through this, and work out what's going on, and compare with yours to see what your mistake was. It'll help you learn, honestly. :)#

Comment: The button works fine! but it takes me back to the android home screen. WHy is that?

Comment: Get rid of the line `finish()`. That closes the activity you're in and will send you back to the last activity (which I assume is your android home screen). Then you need to make sure you call `startActivity(intent)` where you used to have `finish()`. That will start the activity you created in the lines above.

Comment: Both you guys are awesome thanks !! I observed both answers and i learnt so much thanks!!!!